# Set TCAdefaults in TYPO3 Page TS config for a specific page type only

Tags: configuration, typo3, backend

I can disable fields in the Page TS Config depending on the selected content type. For example:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.header.types.gridelements_pi1.disabled = 1
```

When I try to set a default value for a specific content type this does not work:

```
TCAdefaults.tt_content.header_layout.types.gridelements_pi1 = 100
```

Does anybody know how to achive, settings a default value for a specific page type?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "selected/specific page type"? Your first example applies to a specific content type (gridelements_pi1) not a page type.

Comment: My bad. Changed page to content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not possible to set the default value for a specific content element. PageTS reference doesn't mention such an option.

It is possible to manipulate the options array to some extent:
See here for possible actions: http://docs.typo3.org/TYPO3/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TCEform/Index.html#pagetceformconfobj

You could experiment with the option **itemsProcFunc** but I have no idea if it'S useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I suspected.